# Trouble adding footer to ListView

Tags: android, listview, footer, listactivity

I have a ListView that I'm trying to add a footer to.  For some reason, it won't show up.  My footer is defined in a separate XML layout called layout_footer.

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_footer, getListView(), false);
getListView().addFooterView(v);
```

Here is the code in my ListActivity's onCreate method.  Please note that it is the last thing I do in onCreate.

I want this item to scroll with the rest of the list and, according to the resources I've found, I believe this is how you do it.  Unfortunately, the footer does not show :(

Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently if I add the footer before setting the Adapter, it works

Comment: Thanks Andrew for sharing your solutions which saved my time!!

Comment: FYI, this is no longer the case on 4.4+